# JFreeChart PolarPlot remove radius labels?

Tags: java, plot, jfreechart

Any ideas? There is no `setRadiusLabelsVisible(...)` or `setLabelGenerator(null)` method which exists for at least some of the other charts. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a [`PolarPlot`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/PolarPlot.html) has a radial `Axis`, so

```
PolarPlot plot = (PolarPlot) chart.getPlot();
ValueAxis axis = plot.getAxis();
axis.setTickLabelsVisible(false);
```

Comment: Hey, since you seem to know a lot about this, could you please take a look at my other question? That would be awesome. Cheers!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433980/plot-points-instead-of-lines-jfreechart-polarchart