# Plot points instead of lines? JFreeChart PolarChart

Tags: plot, jfreechart

Currently, the PolarChart joins all the coordinates with lines creating a polygon. I just want it to plot each point with a dot and NOT join them together. Is this possible?

I have tried using `translateValueThetaRadiusToJava2D()` and Graphics2D to draw circles but it's very clunky and contrived.

Any suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So the `DefaultPolarItemRenderer` takes in all the polar points, converts the polar points to regular Java2D coordinates, makes a `Polygon` with those points and then draws it. Here's how I got it to draw dots instead of a polygon:

```
public class MyDefaultPolarItemRenderer extends DefaultPolarItemRenderer {

    @Override
    public void drawSeries(java.awt.Graphics2D g2, java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D dataArea, PlotRenderingInfo info, PolarPlot plot, XYDataset dataset, int seriesIndex) {


        int numPoints = dataset.getItemCount(seriesIndex);
        for (int i = 0; i < numPoints; i++) {

            double theta = dataset.getXValue(seriesIndex, i);
            double radius = dataset.getYValue(seriesIndex, i);
            Point p = plot.translateValueThetaRadiusToJava2D(theta, radius,
                    dataArea);
            Ellipse2D el = new Ellipse2D.Double(p.x, p.y, 5, 5);
            g2.fill(el);
            g2.draw(el);
        }
    }
}
```

and then instantiated this class elsewhere:

```
    MyDefaultPolarItemRenderer dpir = new MyDefaultPolarItemRenderer();
    dpir.setPlot(plot);
    plot.setRenderer(dpir);
```

Answer (score 2):

This one's a little harder. Given a `PolarPlot`, you can obtain its [`AbstractRenderer`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/AbstractRenderer.html) and set the shape. For example,

```
PolarPlot plot = (PolarPlot) chart.getPlot();
AbstractRenderer ar = (AbstractRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
ar.setSeriesShape(0, ShapeUtilities.createDiamond(5), true);
```

The diamond will appear in the legend, but the [`DefaultPolarItemRenderer`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/DefaultPolarItemRenderer.html) neither renders shapes, nor provides line control. You'd have to extend the default renderer and override `drawSeries()`. [`XYLineAndShapeRenderer`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYLineAndShapeRenderer.html) is good example for study; you can see how it's used in [`TimeSeriesChartDemo1`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/demo/TimeSeriesChartDemo1.html).

If this is *terra incognita* to you, I'd recommend [*The JFreeChart Developer Guide*](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/devguide.html)<sup>†</sup>.

<sup>†</sup><sub>*Disclaimer: Not affiliated with Object Refinery Limited; I'm a satisfied customer and very minor contributor.*</sub>

Answer (score 1):

This is an excellent discussion, in case you want the function to pick up the color assigned by user to the series

add ...

```
Color c =(Color)this.lookupSeriesPaint(seriesIndex);
g2.setColor(c);
```

before ...

```
g.draw(e1);
```

there are other functions... use code completion to see what else functions are available against series rendereing with name starting from `lookupSeries........(int seriesindex)`

Answer (score 1):

I found a rather strange way to get the points without any lines connecting them.

I set the [Stroke](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BasicStroke.html) of the [renderer](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/DefaultPolarItemRenderer.html) to be a thin line, with a dash phase of 0, and length of 1e10:

```
Stroke dashedStroke = new BasicStroke(
                          0.0f, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND,
                          0.0f, new float[] {0.0f, 1e10f}, 1.0f );
renderer.setSeriesStroke(0, dashedStroke);
```