# Tick mark visiable in polar chart in jfree chart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am working in polar chart using the jfree library in java. I need show the "Radius tick mark" in the polar chart. I have previously worked in jfree line chart but I am new in polar chart.

I need to get it like this:

[image: Image of the chart]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you provide the code you tried ? What happened? Might be easier to help with a working stackblitz , as a rule of thumb always give more details and source code when looking for help.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2430561/230513).

Answer (score 1):

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2430561/230513), a `PolarPlot` is typically created with a radial `Axis`. While the tick labels on the axis are visible by default, [`ChartFactory.createPolarChart()`](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart/blob/d03e68acaff59e7ba1b3573af3c45c9b028f715d/src/main/java/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.java#L1367) disables them:

```
rangeAxis.setTickMarksVisible(false);
```

If you have created your chart using the factory, simply enable the tick marks:

```
PolarPlot plot = (PolarPlot) chart.getPlot();
ValueAxis axis = plot.getAxis();
axis.setTickLabelsVisible(true);
```

Alternatively, create the plot yourself, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3458824/230513), and leave the tick labels enabled:

```
ValueAxis radiusAxis = new NumberAxis();
…
PolarPlot plot = new PolarPlot(dataset, radiusAxis, renderer);
```

[image: polar plot with radial tick labels]